# Create Mobile Device Management Server for iPhone Management on Windows Server

Tags: security, certificate, iphone, configuration-management

I need to create Mobile Device Management server to manage my enterprise's iPhone devices. I need to configuration it on Windows 2008 server. What are the steps to configure Mobile Device Management server for iPhone management on Windows 2008 server?

Comment: Why would you ask this here? the software comes with installation and setup documentation - ServerFault is for professional sysadmins, who do their own homework and look to the vendor first before asking here.

Answer (score 0):

This is not going to "just work", you'll need a specific applianance for this. Might run on the same server, might require a seperate machine. Searching for mobile device management solutions should get you on the right path....